# Excel making a HTTP request in VBA gives a certificate popup leading to a 403 on some machines

Tags: excel, vba, https, certificate

My PC has no issue making a HTTP request:

```
Dim requestObject As Object

Set requestObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With requestObject
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
End With
```

However on some dev machines we get this popup:

[image: Cert Popup]

Clicking 'OK' gives a 403 http response.

Any idea what's occurring here? Making this request in the browser doesn't give any certificate errors/warnings.

Comment: Please, try using `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` instead `"MSXML2.XMLHTTP"`. Then, `.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2)`, followed by `.Open "GET", url, False`, then `.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"` and ending with `.send ("")`. It may work...

Comment: This gives me 403 Forbidden Access Denied, looking up ServerXMLHttp vs just XMLHttp it looks like the latter does a lot more stuff like navigating proxies and sending credentials etc whereas ServerXMLHttp doesn't do anything like that so something important is not being sent/handled.

Comment: Please, add "user", "password" as new parameters at '.Open'. I am driving now...

Comment: Do the dev machines go through a proxy / vpn etc where different firewall in place not configured for this traffic?